# How does the method menuDataRender() get its input for menuList?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Looking at the following snips from the [Ant Design Pro work](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/blob/master/src/layouts/BasicLayout.tsx) work, how does the method `menuDataRender` get its parameters?  The reason I ask this, is because I want to modify the signature, and given the current calling method, there does not appear to be any parameters being passed.

The method:

```
const menuDataRender = (menuList: MenuDataItem[]): MenuDataItem[] =>
  menuList.map(item => {
    const localItem = {
      ...item,
      children: item.children ? menuDataRender(item.children) : [],
    };
    return Authorized.check(item.authority, localItem, null) as MenuDataItem;
  });
```

The caller:

```
  //
  //    ... code removed for brevity ...
  //
  return (
    <>
      <ProLayout
        logo={logo}
        menuHeaderRender={(logoDom, titleDom) => (
          <Link to="/">
            {logoDom}
            {titleDom}
          </Link>
        )}
        onCollapse={handleMenuCollapse}
        menuItemRender={(menuItemProps, defaultDom) => {
          if (menuItemProps.isUrl || menuItemProps.children) {
            return defaultDom;
          }

          return <Link to={menuItemProps.path}>{defaultDom}</Link>;
        }}
        breadcrumbRender={(routers = []) => [
          {
            path: '/',
            breadcrumbName: formatMessage({
              id: 'menu.home',
              defaultMessage: 'Home',
            }),
          },
          ...routers,
        ]}
        itemRender={(route, params, routes, paths) => {
          const first = routes.indexOf(route) === 0;
          return first ? (
            <Link to={paths.join('/')}>{route.breadcrumbName}</Link>
          ) : (
            <span>{route.breadcrumbName}</span>
          );
        }}
        footerRender={footerRender}
        menuDataRender={menuDataRender}                                        // <--- called here!
        formatMessage={formatMessage}
        rightContentRender={rightProps => <RightContent {...rightProps} />}
        {...props}
        {...settings}
      >
        <Authorized authority={authorized!.authority} noMatch={noMatch}>
          {children}
        </Authorized>
      </ProLayout>
      <SettingDrawer
        settings={settings}
        onSettingChange={config =>
          dispatch({
            type: 'settings/changeSetting',
            payload: config,
          })
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProLayout` is the `BasicLayout` component that comes from the `@ant-design/pro-layout` package and this component can receive a `route` prop, which defaults to ([GitHub](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro-layout/blob/e021658cce8bd2d381e2cb17f4c6b89ec3dbd531/src/BasicLayout.tsx#L200-L202)):

```js
route = {
  routes: [],
}
```

The value of the `routes` key (an empty array by default) is used to call the `menuDataRender` function ([GitHub](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro-layout/blob/e021658cce8bd2d381e2cb17f4c6b89ec3dbd531/src/BasicLayout.tsx#L256-L263)):

```js
const { routes = [] } = route;

if (menuDataRender) {
  renderMenuInfoData = getMenuData(
    routes,
    menu,
    formatMessage,
    menuDataRender,
  );
}
```

The expected schema for the elements in the routes array is an array of `Route` type ([GitHub](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro-layout/blob/e021658cce8bd2d381e2cb17f4c6b89ec3dbd531/src/typings.ts#L17-L33)):

```
export interface MenuDataItem {
  authority?: string[] | string;
  children?: MenuDataItem[];
  hideChildrenInMenu?: boolean;
  hideInMenu?: boolean;
  icon?: string;
  locale?: string;
  name?: string;
  key?: string;
  path?: string;
  [key: string]: any;
  parentKeys?: string[];
}

export interface Route extends MenuDataItem {
  routes?: Route[];
}
```

### Example:

```
// routes.ts
import { MenuDataItem } from "@ant-design/pro-layout/lib/typings";

const routes : MenuDataItem[] = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    authority: []
  },
  {
    path: "/users",
    name: "Users",
    authority: ["admin"]
  }
];

export default routes;
```

```
// app.ts
import React from "react";

import ProLayout, {
  MenuDataItem,
  BasicLayoutProps as ProLayoutProps,
} from "@ant-design/pro-layout";

import routeList from "./routes";

const Application: React.FC<ProLayoutProps> = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;

  // or get your route list from where you have it (ex. from a store ...)
  // const routeList = useStoreState(state => state.app.routeList);

  const route = { routes: routeList };

  const menuDataRender = (menuList: MenuDataItem[]): MenuDataItem[] =>
    menuList.map(item => {
      const localItem = {
        ...item,
        children: item.children ? menuDataRender(item.children) : [],
      };
      return Authorized.check(item.authority, localItem, null) as MenuDataItem;
    });

  return (
    <ProLayout
      // more props
      route={route}
      menuDataRender={menuDataRender}
    >
     { children }
    </ProLayout>
  );
}
```